# I'm trying to load this table via JS file

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I'm thinking of adding a table in my js file.

What i want is :

This is my table

```
NewTable = '\
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">\
  <tbody>\
    <tr>\
      <th style="vertical-align: top; text-align:center;">\
        <span id="Pet_Name">\
          Pet Name\
        </span>\
        <br>\
        <span id="Pet_Cost">\
          $\
        </span>\
      </th>\
    </tr>\
  </tbody>\
</table>\
'
```

I want to add this to js file and load it from bookmarklet as soon as bookmarklet is click I want this on there browser.

Or I want to know if i can add Div or whatever is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can! Create a new div element in the body of the page and set the table you have in your question as the innerHTML.

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = '<table>...</table>'; 
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(container)
```